# Is there a way to have a public member, unmodifiable from outside the class, without accessor wrapper function?

Tags: c++, c++17

As far as I know, this seems to be impossible in a straightforward way. Making the member const makes it const for everyone. I would like to have a read-only property, but would like to avoid the typical "getter". I'd like const public, mutable private. Is this at all possible in C++?
Currently all I can think of is some trickery with templates and `friend`. I'm investigating this now.

Might seem like a stupid question, but I have been surprised by answers here before.

Comment: almost everything is possible with some effort, but is it worth the effort? Why do you want this?

Comment: @tobi Not everything is possible, and how can one know the effort involved if one doesn't know what the work involved is? I want this because it seems useful in giving a library user an easy-to use interface, with less indirections than usually applicable.

Comment: @rubenvb: Regardless of the work involved, the result would be cruel, unusual, and worst of all, clever. Is that really something you'd want to unleash on your successors who will have to maintain your code?

Comment: You already spelled out the solution: Make it `const` and use `const_cast` in your class members that need to modify the class member. Completely unusual, unexpected, surprising. Don't try to do this in anything you plan to share.

Comment: @IInspectable that would be undefined behaviour to boot. `const_cast` is only legal if the underlying value is actually not `const`.

Comment: The obvious problem i see is when I have access to a public member that looks const to me then I would just get it once and ignore any changes you make to it. It wouldnt really be easy to use, but rather easy to use wrong

Comment: @rubenvb Something like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vZEndVXKdA8rUEya) that emulates what you want? It works since C++98.

Comment: @rubenvb: That's true, I overlooked that. Anyway, if there is a solution, it would still be surprising to anyone reading the code. Make it a read-only accessor (if you don't want to use compiler-specific extensions, that make accessors look like normal fields; there is one for Microsoft's compiler).

Comment: @skypjack: quite like what I'm after, but perhaps in a more reusable form. I'm thinking in the same direction.

Comment: @rubenvb I'll put it in an answer and try to go a bit further. Feel free to give any suggestion to improve it for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution can be based on an inner class of which the outer one is a friend, like the following one:

```
struct S {
    template<typename T>
    class Prop {
        friend struct S;
        T t;
        void operator=(T val) { t = val; }
    public:
        operator const T &() const { return t; }
    };

    void f() {
        prop = 42;
    }

    Prop<int> prop;
};

int main() {
    S s;
    int i = s.prop;
    //s.prop = 0;
    s.f();
    return i, 0;
}
```

As shown in the example, the class `S` can modify the property from within its member functions (see `S::f`). On the other side, the property cannot be modified in any other way but still read by means of the given operator that returns a const reference to the actual variable.

Comment: I like the general idea, but this is missing some reusability sauce (same template for readonly and writable properties) and associated enable_if herbs :p.

Comment: @rubenvb Well, you want to break encapsulation but get its benefits back. Somehow devilish!! :-)

Comment: So, by adding about 10 lines of code we no longer have to write `()` when we access the value. Is this an improvement?  :-)  I get a vision of guys writing `using namespace std;` to save one use of the `std::` prefix. That is, using 20 bytes to "save" 5 bytes.

Comment: @BoPersson I didn't say I would recommend it. I tried only to reply to the question. ;-)

Comment: @Bo Persson, of course it does not make sense for just one member. But it would with multiple members, not to avoid the parenthesis, but to avoid implementing a getter for each. By the way, one could use `operator()` to get the exact same syntax than a classic getter. And the `Prop` class could be defined elsewhere for re-usability.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be another, more obvious solution: use a public const reference member, pointing to the private, mutable, member. [live code here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5k9tKO5irGlzxuAj).

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
  private:
    int member;
  public:
    const int& prop;
    S() : member{42}, prop{member} {}
    S(const S& s) : member{s.member}, prop{member} {}
    S(S&& s) : member(s.member), prop{member} {}
    S& operator=(const S& s) { member = s.member; return *this; }
    S& operator=(S&& s) { member = s.member; return *this; }
    void f() { member = 32; }
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    S s;
    int i = s.prop;

    cout << i << endl;
    cout << s.prop << endl;

    S s2{s};

    // s.prop = 32; // ERROR: does not compile
    s.f();

    cout << s.prop << endl;
    cout << s2.prop << endl;

    s2.f();
    S s3 = move(s2);

    cout << s3.prop << endl;

    S s4;
    cout << s4.prop << endl;
    s4 = s3;
    cout << s4.prop << endl;
    s4 = S{};
    cout << s4.prop << endl;
}
```

Comment: This makes your class unmovable/unassignable. Maybe redefine those operators?

Comment: It consumes extra space in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I like @skypjack's answer, but would have written it somehow like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Parent, class Value> class ROMember {
  friend Parent;
  Value v_;
  inline ROMember(Value const &v) : v_{v} {}
  inline ROMember(Value &&v) : v_{std::move(v)} {}
  inline Value &operator=(Value const &v) {
    v_ = v;
    return v_;
  }
  inline Value &operator=(Value &&v) {
    v_ = std::move(v);
    return v_;
  }
  inline operator Value& () & {
    return v_;
  }
  inline operator Value const & () const & {
    return v_;
  }
  inline operator Value&& () && {
    return std::move(v_);
  }

public:
  inline Value const &operator()() const { return v_; }
};

class S {
  template <class T> using member_t = ROMember<S, T>;

public:
  member_t<int> val = 0;
  void f() { val = 1; }
};

int main() {
  S s;
  std::cout << s.val() << "\n";
  s.f();
  std::cout << s.val() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Some `enable_if`s are missing to really be generic to the core, but the spirit is to make it re-usable and to keep the calls looking like getters.

This is indeed a *trickery* with `friend`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use curiously recurring template pattern and friend the super class from within a property class like so:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

template<typename Super, typename T>
class property {
  friend Super;

  protected:
    T& operator=(const T& val)
    { value = val; return value; }

    T& operator=(T&& val)      
    { value = val; return value; }

    operator T && () &&
    { return std::move(value); }

  public:
    operator T const& () const& 
    { return value; }

  private:
    T value;
};

struct wrap {
  wrap() {
    // Assign OK
    prop1 = 5; // This is legal since we are friends
    prop2 = 10;
    prop3 = 15;

    // Move OK
    prop2 = std::move(prop1);
    assert(prop1 == 5 && prop2 == 5);

    // Swap OK
    std::swap(prop2, prop3);
    assert(prop2 == 15 && prop3 == 5);
  }
  property<wrap, int> prop1;
  property<wrap, int> prop2;
  property<wrap, int> prop3;
};

int foo() {
  wrap w{};
  w.prop1 = 5;    // This is illegal since operator= is protected
  return w.prop1; // But this is perfectly legal 
}
```

Comment: This just restates an existing answer